Issue in Chapter 9 of Markov Processes for Stochastic Modeling by Oliver C. Ibe
While deriving Brownian Motion from a random walk X(t) with infinitely small time intervals $\Delta t$ and infinitely small increments $\Delta x$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)] = (2p-1)\Delta x \\
\mathbb{E}[[X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)]^{2}] = (\Delta x)^{2}
\end{equation}
after reaching time $t$, therefore $[\frac{t}{\Delta t}]$ (largest integer smaller or equal to $\frac{t}{\Delta t}$) steps; we correctly deduce that the expected value of the sum of these idd is the sum of the expected values, so $[\frac{t}{\Delta t}] (2p-1)\Delta x$.
But how is it that the variance of the sum of idd's is $[\frac{t}{\Delta t}](\Delta x)^{2}$, instead of $[\frac{t}{\Delta t}]4(\Delta x)^{2}p (1-p)$; since that is the correct variance of a single step using the formula
\begin{equation}
Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)]^{2}] - (\mathbb{E}[X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)])^2
\end{equation}

this derivation works only if we set $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$, which is what every other source at my disposal does
Is it a hidden step or missing step?
